# Disable Outlook Addin JS API

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an use case where the addin should be enabled on specific machines instead of all the machines automatically.
Does bt:Url field in manifest.xml support that ?
If the Url is unreachable, mail should be allowed by default instead of being blocked (which is the default response from Outlook)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SskHF.png)

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to bridge the gap (solutions for your scenario):

1. Administrators can disable the on-send policy by ensuring the user's group policy setting `Block send when web add-ins can't load` is set to `Disabled`. To manage this policy setting, you can do the following:

   1. Download the latest `Administrative Templates` tool.
   2. Open the `Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc)`.
   3. Navigate to `User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Outlook 2016 > Security > Trust Center`.
   4. Select the `Block send when web add-ins can't load` setting.
   5. Open the link to edit policy setting.
   6. In the `Block send when web add-ins can't load` dialog window, select `Enabled` or `Disabled` as appropriate then select `OK` or `Apply` to put the update into effect.
2. In the `onSend` event handler you may detect the mailbox or call an external web service which can give the answer whether to run your workload for a specific user / mailbox or not. Following that way you will be able to run your stuff for particular users only.

Read more about that in the [Install Outlook add-ins that use on-send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows#install-outlook-add-ins-that-use-on-send) artice.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
1st option seems to be viable option and we are evaluating it.

But I didn't understand the 2nd option.
If the addin itself is not loaded, how is it possible to detect the mailbox or call an external web service ?
If addin is loadable, the JS callback function is called and we can do above.

Comment: If the add-in is not loaded then the send operation is canceled.

Comment: If the add-in is not loaded, then send operation needs to be allowed. Thats my requirement.

My idea is to have Url with "https://localhost:3000/index.html" (in manifest.xml) and host https web server locally on machine. If that server is not available, then just allow sending the mail.

Comment: We didn't find the equivalent settings in Outlook 365 Admin console. This was for Windows.

Comment: Take a look at the group policy templates for Office.

Answer (score 0):

Would [Smart Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough) (in preview) help you achieve your goal here?

Note, you can specify SendMode option in the manifest for a Smart Alert. There are three options available - PromptUser, SoftBlock and Block. With the SoftBlock option, if the add-in is unavailable (for example, there's an error loading the add-in), the item will be sent.

Comment: We are supporting Mac now and Windows later. But Smart Alerts support is available only on Windows.
Is there any plan to support for Mac ?